# Detect if Tooltip is shown?

Tags: c#, winforms, tooltip, visibility

I am manually displaying a System.Windows.Forms.Tooltip on a control using the show method, but how can I detect if a tooltip is currently shown?

If I need to change the method for showing it to find out, that is fine.

Comment: If you are using .Net 3.0 or 3.5, there is a flag IsOpen for that. For 2.0 framework, I guess ToolTip.Active would help. Not sure though.

Comment: `IsOpen` is only a property on WPF tooltips, not on winforms tooltips.

Comment: The ToolTip.Active property is independent of whether the ToolTip is showing.  It stays however your code sets it, until your code changes it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try ToolTip.GetToolTip(control), and check if the returned value is not an empty string, like this:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(myToolTip.GetToolTip(myControl)))
{
    // Victory!
}
```

Comment: `GetToolTip` (tested for winforms) only checks if `SetToolTip` method was called for that `Control`; If so, the text will be returned, regardless if the tooltip is shown or not. As far as I've seen, there is no relation between the returned value of `GetToolTip` and if `Show` was called.

Comment: This accepted answer is flat-out wrong.  This does not tell you if the ToolTip is currently being displayed or not, it only gets the text value of the ToolTip for the control.

Answer (score 3):

I had so much trouble with the builtin tooltip that I built my own with a timer and tracking MouseMoved.

Answer (score 1):

If this is the only tooltip that can possibly be shown, use Tommy's solution.

If there are tooltips outside of your control, you could enumerate all Tooltip windows and check if one of them is

a) shown

b) within your form/applications bounds

somewhat like this:

```
Native.EnumWindows ew = new Native.EnumWindows();
ew.GetWindows();


foreach (EnumWindowsItem item in ew.Items)
{
    //find all windows forms tooltips currently visible
    if (item.ClassName.StartsWith("WindowsForms10.tooltips_class32") && item.Visible)
    {
        //check if tooltip is on within form bounds
        if (item.Location.X >= this.Location.X && item.Location.Y >= this.Location.Y && 
            item.Location.X <= this.Location.X + this.Width &&
            item.Location.Y <= this.Location.Y + this.Height)
        {
            //Tooltip currently shown within form bounds
        }
    }

}
```

using [this code](http://www.koders.com/csharp/fid4CB5C44EF42AFC04F4AA921220968210292B4D9B.aspx) for the [EnumWindows](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fms633497.aspx&ei=U40qSvfrDNKksAbL3b2eDA&usg=AFQjCNHKHFPlxEMCcPu-tQhVLiuHlavrmg) interop wrapper. 
It's a bit of a hack and if Tommy's solution works for you, it is **much** better.

Comment: This looks like it would be a very useful algorithm, but the link to the EnumWindows wrapper is broken. So far I haven't found it in my Internet searches. If anyone knows where to get this code, could you post it, or at least an updated link?